# installing matplotlib on gcp vm

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I tried to install matplotlib ( third party lib) on gcp vm and failed.

gcp vm python documantation says `use pip install -t lib/ <library_name>` but actually, what they really mean: i.g. `use pip install matplotlib -t lib/ <library_name>` And it didn't work

I tried:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib -t env/gcplib
```

result:

```
"**Failed building wheel for subprocess32**"

"Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-Rpkv8i/subprocess32/setup.py
';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __fi
le__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-x4Y1E4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --co
mpile" **failed with error code 1** in /tmp/pip-install-Rpkv8i/subprocess32/"
```

I will very appreciate any help

Comment: Try following the instructions and replacing `pip install -t lib/ <library_name>` with `matplotlib`: `pip install -t lib/ matplotlib`

Comment: Not a solution but a possible workaround, why not use https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Before attempting to install `matplotlib`, you need to install `python-dev`. You didn't mention what OS your VM was, but if it's Ubuntu, you would do that with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am using Linux debian on gcp and already did what you suggested. I tried again, python-dev is already installed. But installing matplotlib doesn't work, the same.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what distro you're trying to install this package on?

Comment: I used following command on gcp vm instance shell to find out the distro: "lsb_release -a" and the response: "No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.8 (stretch)
Release:        9.8
Codename:       stretch" - I can use matplotlib on gcp shell but NOT on gcp vm instance shell